# Input field filter solution for jQuery

Tags: jquery

Anyone know a good solution for filtering input using jQuery?

I'd like to do something like this:

$("#fieldname").InputFilter("###-###-####")

I would also like the visual interface to enforce and display placeholders for ###-###-####, #####, etc.

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: Wish it did optional characters though ... e.g. Zip Codes #####(-####) ... but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Latest version supports option input. In the example from the previous comment, the syntax would be `$("#zipcode).mask("99999?-9999")`; everything after the ? is optional input. My feature request is a simple character filter (or even better, a repeated character filter). It can be pulled off reasonably well with jquery-validate plugin, but it would be nice to roll those together.